# How to determine the height of a line so that the sum of areas made with another curve over a specific domain is zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a question which asks to determine the height of a level road to be built in a mountain so that cutting and filling costs are minimised. To elaborate, the earth that will be removed from hills to make way for the road will be used to fill in valleys. I know that the sum of areas above and below the line of the road must equal zero (the positive areas must equal the negative areas) but I am not sure how to do this without a program.  Below is a graph of the cross-sectional view of the mountain with the given data points.

[image: This is a cross-sectional view of the mountain with the given data. The road must be the length of the domain]

Comment: If you could work out the area below the graph data line (this may involve counting the squares in the graph below the line since you didn't want to use a computer program) then use that area as a rectangle of area.  The length of one side of the rectangle will be the highest $x$ value minus the lowest $x$ value.  So that side will be something like $640$ units long.

Comment: Note that the above comment is equivalent to saying that the line should be at the mean of the given heights.

Comment: @joriki To clarify, not mean of the heights of the given points. It has to be an overall mean of the function.

Comment: @mniip: Right; thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you post the profile data somewhere (as an external link, or a reasonable number of the coordinates in the question itself)?